# AngularJS contenteditable compiling contents on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a contenteditable input like so.

```
<div contenteditable input-container></div>
```

An external event may add html content into the contenteditable. It could be plain html text, or html with a directive. So for example i might end up with

```
<div contenteditable input-container>
    <some-directive></some-directive>
</div>
```

So, when the contenteditable content changes, i need to recompile. I'm doing that like so:

```
module.directive('inputContainer', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('change', function(){
                console.log("Compile main input content");
                $compile(element.html())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Assuming the inner directive to be like this:

```
module.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<span>***test***</span>",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            console.log(element.html());
        }
    };
});
```

Problem is that everything *seems* to run fine, no errors and the console logs are where they're expected to be, but the page is not updated and it's not showing the expected

```
***test***
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it, the error is here

```
$compile(element.html())(scope);
```

`$compile` expects DOM elements, not html text. So the replacing with the follwing fixed

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```